# Is cookie writing expensive?

Tags: web-applications, cookies

Does writing cookies slow down a web response in any perceivable way? For example, would writing a few cookies on each request of a web application have an effect on performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not that expensive, but it does add some overhead, mainly in that extra information is sent back and forth, and the web browser sends the cookies back with each subsequent request.  Unless you want a REST style interface I wouldn't worry too much as long as your not filling the cookies up with a large amount of data.